# What does "by heaven" mean?

Tags: phrases

What does "by heaven" mean here?

> I should be far enough from imagining, he replied, that I knew the cause of any of them, **by heaven** I should;

Comment: It's just an exclamation like 'indeed!' or 'forsooth!'. Kind of old-fashioned, not really used anymore. There's not much additional literal meaning to 'by heaven I should', it just means that the speaker is intensifying what he just said.

Comment: It's shortened from something like *"I swear by heaven/God/Jesus/etc."* As reflected in other "minced oaths" such as archaic ***Egad!*** and Irish ***Bejasuz!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the same thing as "by God", and it probably came about because people wanted to avoid saying "God" in vain. Similar to words like "gosh" or "golly".

Comment: http://youtu.be/lNPcqunKBvI?t=47s